# setting up git ssh access error: gitosis need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

When I go to set up git to run with `ssh`, I get the following error:

```
file "usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.5.egg/gitosis/init.py", 
line 35, in ssh_extract_user 
_, user = pubkey.rsplit(None, 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

the command I typed:

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/sean/.ssh/pubkey.pub
```

I am running the ubuntu long release server 8.04

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this by modifying generated public key file, at the end it has user name appended,remove special characters and register public key with gitosis.

If public key is

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E ....... .....
>   .....==
>   user@3435-343-3434.somedomain.com

update this as

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E ....... .....
>   .....== user@somedomain.com

Further refer https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=470359

Answer (score 4):

This should be related to your ssh key format, as [illustrated by this thread](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

> I used `PuttyGen` on Windows to generate my public key (`SSH2 RSA 1024`) and save it locally, and then I uploaded it to `/tmp/id_rsa.pub` using `pscp`, but then when I ran

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```

> I kept getting errors, eg:

```
gitosis.init.InsecureSSHKeyUsername: Username contains not allowed characters: ‘—‘
```

> or:

```
gitosis.init.InsecureSSHKeyUsername: Username contains not allowed characters:’”rsa-key-20081202”’
```

> or (after I got rid of everything in the file but the key itself):

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

> I figured that `PuttyGen` had generated an `SSH2` public key file in a slightly different format, and ‘`git gitosis-init`’ wanted a user name at the beginning, so I went here:

http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4716

> and saw that I could keep the “`—BEGIN…`” and “`—END`” parts, and replace the “`comment: ...`” line (generated by PuttyGen) with a line reading:

```
subject: git
```

> And it worked! I got the output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/ 
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
```

Answer (score 0):

this key worked for me 
puttygen on windows, ssh-2-rsa, 1024

```
ssh-rsa user@domain.com
AAAAB3N-lksdfwejekjvcjsndgefjhbdfzuegjksafdiuewhdskajdfeiudhksj
...
...
GncwFuk=
```